# Alias for variable of type struct in C

Tags: c, struct, reference

I would like to create (some type of) "alias" to a struct object in C.

Based on a variable, `a` should be `x` or `y`. But it should not be copied, it needs to be a reference to that `a`-object.

Some code:

```
void search(node start, node end) {
    int myid = omp_get_thread_num();
    node localstart;
    if (myid == 0) {
        // start correct way
        localstart = start; // <-- how?!
    }
    else{
        // start reversed way
        localstart = end; // <-- how?!
    }
    // do something with localstart eg.:
    localstart->dist = 0;
    // now should 
    // start->dist == 0 or end->dist == 0 (based on myid)
    // be true!
}
```

The code is some part of a bidirectional search. One thread should start at the start and search for the end and the other one should start at the end and search for the start.

On the other hand, I could call a function with start and end (and reversed). But also here, I would need to pass the struct as reference.
I would like to use the first idea, if possible!

Comment: Declare `node localstart;` before the `if`..?

Comment: ah, sorry, yes i did! I'll correct that!

Comment: By far the best way to write that, in my opinion, is to call the function in each thread with the appropriate parameters. Leave the function to just do the searching; have the calling code direct it to do the correct search, with the arguments reversed. I'm not clear how you have the same code searching in the two directions, but that's your problem. You seem to be passing pointers around anyway; when you access `localstart` elements, it appears that `localstart` is a pointer to a structure type, so `start` and `end` are also pointers. Pointers are how you create 'aliases' for variables in C.

Answer (score 1):

In C, you reference a variable using a pointer:

```
node *localstart;
if (myid == 0) {
    // start correct way
    localstart = &start;
}
else {
    // start reversed way
    localstart = &end;
}
(*localstart)->dist = 0;
```

From your usage of `node` it is clear that it is actually a pointer to a structure, so now you have a pointer-to-pointer. Not a problem for the C compiler, it can even optimize away the pointer variable in some cases. Just do not forget the parentheses!